# Создать класс Gradebook, хранящий список студентов

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Тестовое задание Python.

1. Создать класс Gradebook, хранящий список студентов, с именами и фамилиями. Каждый студент имеет информацию о предметах, которые он сдавал. Этой информацией являются две оценки: рейтинговая за семестр и экзаменационная.

   Класс Gradebook должен содержать по меньшей мере следующие методы:

   1. `get_best_exam_student` - принимает параметр subject, возвращает студента с наивысшей экзаменационной отметкой, полученной по subject предмету.
   2. `get_passed_exams` - возвращает все предметы, по которым студенты сдавали экзамены.
   3. `print_result_grades` - выводит в консоль фамилии всех студентов с названиями предметов, которые они сдавали. Напротив каждого предмета выводить общую оценку по предмету для этого студента, которая = рейтинговая*0.3 + экзаменационная*0.7, округлять к ближайшему целому. В итоге вывод должен быть следующим:

      ```
      Student1
        subject1 - result_grade_for_subj1
        subject2 - result_grade_for_subj2
      Student2
        subject1 - result_grade_for_subj1
        subject10 - result_grade_for_subj10 
      ...
      ```

   Протестировать.
2. Создать аналог встроенной в питон функции range/xrange. С одним отличием - ваш аналог должен пропускать каждое третье число

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Gradebook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.students = {}

    def get_best_exam_student(self, subject):
        students = (name for name in self.students if subject in self.students[name])
        students = sorted(students, key=lambda name: self.students[name][subject].get('exam', 0)) or [None]
        return students[-1]

    def get_passed_exams(self):
        return set(subject for subjs in self.students.values() for subject in subjs)

    def print_result_grades(self):
        for name in self.students:
            print(name, ' '.join('{} - {}'.format(n, round(rate['semestr']*.3 + rate['exam']*.7))
                                 for n, rate in self.students[name].items()))

# заполнить тест данными
from random import randrange
G = Gradebook()
student_count = 3
subject_count = 4
max_rate = 12
subjects = ['subject%s' % n for n in range(subject_count)]
for name in (('Name%s' % n, 'Surname%s' % n) for n in range(student_count)):
    G.students[name] = student = {}
    for r in range(randrange(5)):
        subject = subjects[randrange(subject_count)]
        rate = dict(exam=randrange(max_rate), semestr=randrange(max_rate))
        student[subject] = rate
print('\n'.join(map(str, G.students.items())))

# проверить
print(G.get_best_exam_student('subject1'))
print(G.get_passed_exams())
G.print_result_grades()
```

out:

```
(('Name0', 'Surname0'), {'subject0': {'semestr': 11, 'exam': 10}, 'subject2': {'semestr': 6, 'exam': 5}})
(('Name2', 'Surname2'), {'subject1': {'semestr': 5, 'exam': 11}, 'subject2': {'semestr': 11, 'exam': 9}})
(('Name1', 'Surname1'), {'subject1': {'semestr': 1, 'exam': 1}})
('Name2', 'Surname2')
{'subject0', 'subject1', 'subject2'}
('Name0', 'Surname0') subject0 - 10 subject2 - 5
('Name2', 'Surname2') subject1 - 9 subject2 - 10
('Name1', 'Surname1') subject1 - 1
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе @vadim огромное!!!!